# Copied C9 Workspace with Rails app, PostgreSQL service won't start: permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I just copied a C9 workspace with a functional Ruby on Rails app, and can't seem to get the PostgreSQL service running.

running this command:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

returns this error:

```
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2017-08-15 06:50:57 UTC FATAL:  could not remove old lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied
2017-08-15 06:50:57 UTC HINT:  The file seems accidentally left over, but it could not be removed. Please remove the file by hand and try again.
```

after deleting this file manual and running again:

```
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2017-08-15 07:01:45 UTC FATAL:  could not access private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key": Permission denied
```

I'm guessing I need to setup some permission access to PostgreSQL, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` actually exists?

Comment: Yes it does but I have to go into SuperUser in the console to access it. @Babar

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by running this command:

```
gpasswd -a postgres ssl-cert
```

And then started the postgresql server and it worked just fine!